# JLabel won't display image in class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, jlabel

I'm currently trying to create a GUI in which two images of coins are displayed next to each other in the center of a borderlayout. I have one class (Images) in which I attempt to use JLabel to display the Icons and another class which handles the GUI Frame (GameGUI). However despite my best efforts the labels don't display the images. I've looked through countless tutorials and can't find anything to fix this. The relative paths are correct, how can I fix this?

Images Class

```
public class Images extends JLabel{

    private JLabel heads, tails;

    public Images() {
        heads = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img/heads.png"));
        tails = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img/tails.png"));
        add(heads);
        add(tails);
    }
}
```

GameGUI Class

```
public class GameGUI extends JFrame{

    public GameGUI() {
        super("");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(10,10));

        Menu menu = new Menu();
        ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar();
        Images images = new Images();

        setJMenuBar(menu);

        add(BorderLayout.NORTH, toolBar);
        add(BorderLayout.CENTER, images);

        setSize(1000, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. You are adding **two** Icons to your JLabel, and this won't work -- A JLabel displays only one. 2. If you need to display two, then use two JLabels. 3. Don't extend JLabel, no need and only adds unnecessary confusion. 4. Divide and conquer -- try to solve this for a single label and single image first.

Comment: 5. Such a simple debug program could be to display the icon in a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog, which can take an icon as its second parameter: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, myIcon);`

Comment: My bet: your path to your image file is wrong, and this is why you should divide and conquer first. Also better to get the image as a resource, not as a File as you're doing (indirectly). Use ImageIO.read, and read in the resource, then create the Icon.

Comment: Also: get rid of text in your question that just distracts and doesn't help us understand your problem, such as, `"I've looked through countless tutorials and can't find anything..."` -- useless. Instead add more useful information that might help us help you, such as the location of your image files relative to your user directory and relative to your class files. If you've done such an exhaustive search, you'll already know why this is important.

Comment: Ah, I now see your problem -- you're using a JLabel as a container for other components -- ***never*** do this

Comment: actually there is no need to extend neither a `JFrame` nor the `JLabel` in this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem:

```
public class Images extends JLabel{

    private JLabel heads, tails;

    public Images() {
        heads = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img/heads.png"));
        tails = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img/tails.png"));
        add(heads);
        add(tails);
    }
}
```

JLabels use a null layout, meaning your internal JLabel components will have a size of 0, 0, and the Images JLabel itself will have a preferred size of the same, and nothing will show, and so you never want to add a JLabel to a JLabel. Don't have images extend JLabel, but rather JPanel, and give it a decent layout, perhaps GridLayout.

e.g.,

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private JLabel headsLabel = new JLabel();
    private JLabel tailsLabel = new JLabel();

    public ImagePanel(Icon headsIcon, Icon tailsIcon) {
        headsLabel.setIcon(headsIcon);
        tailsLabel.setIcon(tailsIcon);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0);
        add(headsLabel);
        add(tailsLabel);
    }       
}
```

Again, I would recommend getting the images as resources, not as Files using ImageIO read, something like

```
Image headImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(resourcePath));
Icon headIcon = new ImageIcon(headImage);
```

the resource path will be critical and will depend on where the images are relative to your class files.

Comment: "JLabels use a null layout, meaning your internal JLabel components will have a size of 0, 0". This ended up being the reason why it wouldn't show. After adding in the GridLayout the images showed perfectly. I'll clean up my code aswell. Thank you for the help

Comment: @Chornologic please note that it is extending a `JPanel` and not a `JLabel`, no need for the *extra* label

Comment: @Chornologic and actually, if this were my code, I wouldn't be extending JPanel unless I needed to override a JPanel method. Better to use composition if possible and not inheritance.